# Memory cards for tablets

Tags: performance, memory-card

I want to learn more about the terminology used in association with high-quality memory cards.

For example, Class 10 is the fastest class available. Above this, UHS-1 makes it even faster.

In addition to those terms, I see other terms used in relation to a card's speed.  For example, suppose one card is specified as "Nitro 566x" and another as "Premium 300x".  What do the 566x & 300x signify?  Do the terms "Nitro" and "Premium" have an officially recognized meaning related to a card's characteristics?  Do any of these terms relate to the card's latency?

Comment: How is this not a shopping request? Also, that 300x and 566x are marketing hype and do not necessarily reflect real-world performance.

Comment: @music2myear - He wants to know which card to purchase....How is that not a shopping question.

Comment: @music2myear I didn't mention anywhere that I want to purchase. Simply I want to know the difference between the 2 cards so that the one that would work better, I will put that in my tablet. I request everyone to please re-read my Q & say where it's shopping related. IT'S not. If one still feels it to be shopping related, please guide me so that I change that sentence orelse please edit my Q yourself. See I'm trying to understand the different cards available & the one that will work best for me. That's all. It's completely technical.

Comment: @Ravi I edited the question a bit, feel free to edit it along those lines, that might help you re-open it.

Answer (score 2):

Premium and nitro are just product lines. The x is just speed. 566x translates to roughly 8 85 Mb/s. 300x translates to roughly 45mb/s, so the Nitro card is faster. I don't think video speed will be affected by either card, although you may notice slight latency with the premium card

Comment: 300x translates to 45 mb/s; it works in that proportion, so 566x translates to 84.9 mb/s. Am I right? Thank you.

Comment: Yeah, I rounded